# How to extend Windows PATH env variable in Sublime Text?

Tags: python, path, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

How do I permanently extend my `PATH` variable from sublime text 3?

Specifically I am doing this for my [scala REPL for the SublimeREPL package](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#frequently-asked-questions)

```
"default_extend_env": {'{PATH};H:\\scala-2.10.2\\bin'},
```

I get "error trying to parse strings" error, and have tried with `"`, and with single `\`.

Comment: have you tried using a forward slash `/`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the key name "PATH":

```
"default_extend_env": { "PATH" : "{PATH};H:\\scala-2.10.2\\bin" }
```

Your full user config file should look like this:

```
{
   "default_extend_env": { "PATH" : "{PATH};H:\\scala-2.10.2\\bin" }
}
```